# Python least squares with scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares

I;m having trouble decyphering an error message for my code to find some parameters to a complicated least squares fit in two parameters (eps and sig).

```
from pylab import *
import scipy
import numpy as np

from scipy import integrate, optimize

# Estimate parameters with least squares fit   
T = [90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300]
B = [-0.2221, -0.18276, -0.15348, -0.13088, -0.11293, -0.09836, -0.086301, -0.076166, -0.067535, -0.060101, -0.053636, -0.047963, -0.04295, -0.038488, -0.034494, -0.030899, -0.027648, -0.02469, -0.022, -0.019534, -0.017268, -0.015181]


def funeval(Temp,eps,sig):
    return -2.*np.pi*scipy.integrate.quad( lambda x: np.exp(4.*eps/Temp*((sig/x)**6.-(sig/x)**12.)*(x**2)) ,0.0,Inf )[0]

def residuals(p,y,Temp):
    eps,sig = p
    err = y-(funeval(Temp,eps,sig) )
    return err

print funeval(90.,0.001, 0.0002) 

plsq = scipy.optimize.leastsq(residuals, [0.00001, 0.0002], args=(B, T))
```

The `funeval` gives a reasonable float but when I run the code it returns:

```
error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.
```

The error doesnt seem sensitive to the initial conditions. I'm new to python so any help or guides to help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `funeval(90.,0.001, 0.0002)`, `Temp` is a singular value; however, when you are calling `scipy.optimize` you are passing the entire `T` array to `funeval` causing `scipy.integrate` to crash.

A quick fix would be to do something like:

```
def funeval(Temp,eps,sig):
    out=[]
    for T in Temp:
        val = scipy.integrate.quad( lambda x: np.expm1( ((4.*eps)/T)* ((sig/x)**12.-(sig/x)**6.)* (x**2.) ), 0.0, np.inf )[0]
        out.append(val)
    return np.array(out)

def residuals(p,y,Temp):
    eps,sig = p
    err = y-(funeval(Temp,eps,sig) )
    return err

print funeval([90],0.001, 0.0002)

plsq = scipy.optimize.leastsq(residuals, [0.00001, 0.0002], args=(B, T))
(array([  3.52991175e-06,   9.04143361e-02]), 1)
```

This, unfortunately, does not converge very well. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help so far. The idea is to calculate the Lennard Jones potential parameters for Argon given data on the second virial coefficient. So the equation describing the relationship is http://i.imgur.com/VfCl5EE.gif

So the idea is to fine epsilon and sigma. (They should be around 120 and 341e-9)

(Still learning SO interface)

Comment: @doubletheron Please view my edit, you were forgetting the `-1`. Also you should use [`np.expm1`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expm1.html), please view the page for the an explanation. You may want to consider weighting the different temperatures.

Comment: I have discovered that textbooks lie. Book 1 (a liar): http://i.imgur.com/fAO4Fdl.jpg

Book 2 (probably telling the truth): http://i.imgur.com/GVJVSaT.jpg

So I fixed the eqn in `funeval` but still no convergence.

Comment: What units is `B` in? Its usually `cm^3/mol`, but this conversion is not present. Is this a homework problem?

Comment: B is in `m^3/kmol` I calculated it in REFPROP for Argon at 1 bar. I wish this were a HW problem, then I would feel confident skipping it; no, it's just something I'm trying to get to work to try to figure out the physics and improve at python.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the help. I think kmol is just a kilomole = 10^3 mol, so you define 1 kmol = 12 kg C-12. I'm sure there's a simple way to get the LJ parameters than from B_2 (maybe spectroscopy data).